# How to use regex param in Nexus v3 groovy scripting

Tags: regex, groovy, nexus3

I need to get in my raw Nexus v3 repository every files that contains a '-' character

Ive found how to use storageFacet to make some queries but I cant find how to use a regex with it:

```
def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get("myRepo")
StorageFacet storageFacet = repo.facet(StorageFacet)

def tx = storageFacet.txSupplier().get()
tx.begin()
Iterable<Component> components =  
tx.findComponents(Query.builder().where('name = ').param('/^.*\b([-]+)\b.*$').build(), [repo])
tx.commit()
tx.close()
```

It works when I put a string name instead of param('/^.*\b([-]+)\b.*$') .

If you have any documentation about how this query system works I will be more than happy to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly used a Like %-%
But I still dont know how to use a Regex in this case.